# InitAudi: Cannot open OSS audio device /dev/dsp

Tags: command-line, sound, alsa, speech-recognition

I'm working on speech recognition with HTK, and when I run HSLab I have this.

```
InitAudi: Cannot open OSS audio device /dev/dsp
```

The sound works normally in other applications.

Any help please?

Comment: You should purge the OSS4 packages, may be

Comment: Thank you for replying, I got this error "apt transaction returned result exit-failed" when i tried to install the packages

Comment: Try 'sudo apt-get install oss-compat'  It adds a compatibility layer between alsa and oss.

Comment: it worked, but i still have the same error, other suggestion please ?

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM RESOLVED**

> sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
>
> sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
>
> sudo apt-get install osspd